# NetLogo - Sandpile Model - Error - If expected 2 inputs

Tags: syntax-error, netlogo

As part of the setup procedure I am trying to use a slider to set the density of patches which will be displayed and assigned a random value. The slider on the interface for density ranges 0 to 100 and the random value of the patch is set using an input on the interface. This will normally be set in the region go 4. So, if 50% is set the the procedure will assign 50% of the patches with a random value.

When i do i get the following error: "If expected 2 inputs, a true/false and a command block" and "if (random-float 100.0) < init-errors" is highlighted in the code.

```
; The density of patches to be set with a random value is set using variable init-errors on interface.
;; Every patch uses a task which reports a random value.
;; The random value is set using variable error-count on interface
to setup-random
   ask patches [
     if (random-float 100.0) < init-errors
     setup task [ random error-count ]
   ]
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#if the syntax of `if` is:

```
if <condition> [ <commands> ]
```

The square brackets are mandatory, but you left them out, hence the error.  (Commands surrounded by square brackets are a "command block", hence the error "expected... a command block".)